# How do I run my code from the command line?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char arg[]){

    int a=arg[1];
    int b=arg[2];
    int c=a+b;
    cout<<c<<endl;


     return 0;
}
```

i am using windows 7 microsoft visual c++ 2010
how run it from command line?

Comment: Perhaps your code should be correct before you try to run it...

Comment: What Cogwheel probably means is that your arg[] declaration is wrong; you need `char* arg[]` giving you string args and you then need to convert these to integers before you can use them, e.g. `int a = atoi(arg[1]);`

Comment: And for the record, you don't need to say 'question about' in the titles of all your... questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Navigate to the directory where the executable (.exe) is located.  Then type the executable's name followed by two integer parameters.

```
C:\TestProg\> TestProg 5 6
```

The problems in your original example are corrected here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *arg[])
{
    std::stringstream sa;
    std::stringstream sb;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    if (argc >= 3)
    {    
        // Convert string parameter into an integer.
        sa.str(arg[1]);
        sa >> a;

        if (!sa)
        {
            return 1;    // error
        }

        // Convert string parameter into an integer.
        sb.str(arg[2]);
        sb >> b;

        if (!sb)
        {
            return 1;    // error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;    // error
    }

    c = a + b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt from the Start Menu. Use the CD command to change directories to where your exe is. type the name of your exe followed by the arguments.

```
foo.exe 1 2
```

or just

```
foo 1 2
```

Expect the output (once you've fixed your numerous code errors):

```
3
```

Comment: I certainly wouldn't expect that output.

Comment: Fair enough, once it is working. But the question I answered was about the actual process of executing and passing arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Once you compile this you get an executable. Navigate to the directory containing the executable and run it.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing that's not exactly helpful. You are making way to many assumptions on implied knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Go to google and look for a windows console tutorial.  You need to start it from the console.  Alternatively you can assign command line in the project properties.  I'd recommend learning to do both.

BTW, this code almost certainly does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

The compiled output of your program will be in the Debug or Release folder inside the solution folder (at least with default project settings). Just change to that directory and run the .exe file.

Comment: This will work for a simple program, but if there are DLLs and other baggage, the program will be looking for the assets in the working directory. The command line needs to be set one directory above where the EXE is located, and the EXE name needs to be preceded with the directory where it is located (C:\MyFolder> Debug\MyApp.exe 2 3)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt (you can find it in the Start Menu)

cd to your source file directory

type:

```
cl.exe <your file name>.cpp
```

It will create a file .exe

Comment: Matthew, that's how to compile and link it, not how to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Once your code is setup properly it would be something like this.

```
MyApp 2 3
```

Or similar